# Not sure about this Hasse Diagram

Tags: order-theory

I'm not sure how to draw Hasse diagram of this set $\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$, $R = \{(a,b)\mid a\leq b\}$. My attempt is just a straight edge with the smallest vertex at the bottom and the greatest at the top and all those vertices in between has one edge in and one edge out. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. The reason is that you have a total order, where the Hasse diagram is just a chain.